# Initialise several variables at once to the same object but different instances

Tags: python, initialization

What is the cleanest way of initialising several objects the same way, without making them all point to the same object? I want to do this:

```
a, b, c = create_object(), create_object(), create_object()
```

In a less verbose way.

I can do the following, but then all my variables point to the same object

```
a = b = c = create_object() # then a.change() changes them all!
```

Is there a clean, pythonic way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: Your first way is the best... If you have too many variables then you should be using a list instead. I'm voting to close this.

Comment: @jamylak If there isn't a cleaner to do it, that's a useful fact to have on SO that I wasn't able to find in any existing questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most *pythonic* code is the code that makes the most *sense*. It's a lot better to just do

```
a = create_object()
b = create_object()
c = create_object()
```

as opposed to the alternative, a confusing mess of gibberish. Don't be afraid of having two extra lines; really, the benefit is much greater. :-)

Comment: How does the OP's original code not make any sense?

Comment: I meant if one were to try to consolidate it into a factory or list or something of that ilk.

Answer (score 1):

Use a factory.

```
def factory(num):
    for i in range(num):
        yield shell()

class shell():
    pass

a, b, c = factory(3)

# results:
>>> a
<__main__.shell instance at 0x0000000002BE0548>
>>> b
<__main__.shell instance at 0x0000000002BE03C8>
>>> c
<__main__.shell instance at 0x0000000002BE0588>
```

You can of course, always add extra parameters to be able to initialize a group of variables to be the same, or you could even have complex factories that determine their own parameters to pass to the class constructor.

You could also have it a static method of the class.

Whatever your preference is, if you want to initialize a group of variables to all be difference instances of the same class, this would be how you should do it. (although, in general, that kind of activity is not very *pythonic* for what it's worth...)

---

To make a factory using what you have shown, and to make it more robust, here is a nice sample:

```
def factory(obj, num, args=None):
    for i in range(num):
        yield obj(args) if args else obj()


a, b, c = factory(create_object, 3)
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of when this would be useful? I would also suggest being able to pass the class to the factory function

Comment: Example: A game that wants to create 10 random critters somewhere on the map, the critter init would take care of positioning, but you want to store those 10 critters into a specific group, maybe create a second group as well... and have 2 groups of 10 random critters, perhaps with slightly different arguments.

Comment: I would just use list comprehensions in that case but I guess that's a matter of style now

Comment: I would not personally go this way either, but I can see why it could be used, and where, and if this is the desired approach, then this is the correct method. Because writing 10 lines of code for 10 variables is ridiculous.

Comment: You would never really need to operator on ten variables seperately anyway

Comment: Like I said, I do not know the use-case, but if one exists, this would be the method to create them.